# React Native FlatList refreshing not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, refresh, flatlist

i got an problem with the refreshing on pull function. The FlatList renders fine, but pull to refresh is not working. This is my current sourcecode:

```
return (
   <View style={GlobalStyles.flex1}>
       <FlatList
           showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
           refreshControl={
               <RefreshControl
                   refreshing={isRefreshing}
                   onRefresh={() => {
                       console.log("onRefresh loadVocable");
                       loadVocables();
                   }}
               />
           }
           data={vocables}
           keyExtractor={vocable => vocable.id}
           onEndReached={() => {
               if (!isRefreshing && !endReached) {
                   loadVocables();
               }
           }}
           renderItem={vocable => (
               <TouchableOpacity
                   onPress={() => {
                       props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: "editVocable", params: { vocable: vocable.item } });
                   }}
                   onLongPress={() => {
                       handleLongPress(vocable.item.id);
                   }}>
                   <Card style={styles.cardStyle}>
                       <View style={styles.part1}>
                           <Text style={styles.vocableText}>{vocable.item.wordENG}</Text>
                           <Text style={styles.vocableText}>{vocable.item.wordDE}</Text>
                       </View>
                       <View style={styles.part2}>
                           <Ionicons name={vocable.item.known ? "md-checkmark-circle" : "md-close-circle"} size={23} color={vocable.item.known ? Colors.success : Colors.danger} />
                       </View>
                   </Card>
               </TouchableOpacity>
           )}
       />
   </View>
);
```

In the [official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol) is an example that says contentContainerStyle needs to be flex: 1 to know the height, that makes sence to me, so when i set contentContainerStyle with flex 1, refresh on pull works fine, but then i can't scroll anymore in the Flatlist and everthing get very tight, so the style also change then. Does anyone know why this happen?

The first picture is with "contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}" and the last one is without contentContainerStyle.

[image: with contentContainerStyle set to flex 1]

[image: without contentContainerStyle]

Comment: Try using flexgrow instead of flex

Comment: @The1993 flexGrow doesn't worked for me, it ends up with the same as picture 2, so everything looks normal, but refresh on pull doesn't work.

Comment: @The1993 I have an update, flexgrow is working, but only when i create a new project. I tried everything but no solution is working, how can i check if my project is broken and what can i do then?

Comment: Honestly, it's very hard to tell what went wrong on your current project. Maybe check for typos or compare both project files and see the diff.

Comment: @The1993 a few days later, i completly reacreated my whole app, i created a complete new project and re setup the android and ios folder for all package that need to be installed, but it's still not working. I checked the project, after creating it and it worked, but after setting up everything it dosen't. So now i'm pretty sure, that my code is the problem, but what else could it be?

Comment: @The1993 omg i go crying, i found the error and it was so simple, how dump am i :D Thanks for the tip to compare both projects, i did it there and found the dumpest error i ever made. The import was wrong, I imported Flatlist from react-native-gesture-handler and not from react-native. For this little thing i lot 5 days of working :D

Comment: nice to hear that you got this working!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was so easy, I compared a new project (there worked my code) to the one where the problem was and after 5 days I found the little error:

My import was wrong!
I imported `FlatList` like this:

```
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

But it needs to get imported from React-Native so like this:

```
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
```

Thanks to [@The1993](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323101/the1993), without the hint to compare the projects, maybe I would stuck forever on this error :D In the future I will compare working files to find any error!

Comment: THANK YOU for posting your question and answer. I had the exact same incorrect import causing the same behavior. 

Answer (score 1):

contentContainerStyle is used to style inner content e.g items alignments, padding, etc

style is used to align its height and relations

You can replace `style={{flex: 1}}` instead of contentContainerStyle or wrap the parent element with `flex: 1`

Comment: I also tryed this, but then nothing happen. The FlatList working fine but as before the refresh on pull function don't work.